# How can I use Viewpager in a fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I want to use the ViewPager as a fragment in my project.Name of my fragment is 'ViewP' and it implements ActionBar.TabListener.
But while fragment transaction I am getting errors

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new ViewP();
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
```

But I am getting errors as

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, ViewP)

Comment: Are you using the right `Fragment`? I.e. are you using the one from the support library? And if so also use the support fragment manager. How is ViewP defined and what `Fragment` class is imported? `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this part after you add fragment:

fragmentTransaction.commit();

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()

(add following at 12:33 pm)

```
Fragment fragment = new ViewP();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I have added this line but getting same error as before

Comment: Try to move new fragment this part on the top, just post sample code in edition.